# how to update table using executesql in web2py

Tags: sql, web2py

I want to Update table `pull_out.po_det` where the `sr_id` is equal to variable `sr_id`, and when I execute the following code below I get a

> An error occured, please reload the page.

Can some one please tell me what is wrong with the code below?

```
def editpo():
    getvars=request.vars.a
    sr_id=request.args(0,cast=int,default=0)
    query=db.pull_out.sr_id==sr_id
    update_po=db.executesql('UPDATE pull_out SET po_det=%s WHERE %s;' %str(getvars) %str(query))
    if update_po:
        response.flash="Pull Out edit successful!"
    return locals()
```

Comment: If you received that error message, I assume the above action was called via an Ajax request. In that case, you should go to the admin app and view the error traceback and post it with your question, as it can be difficult to diagnose your problem without that.

Comment: Also, is there any reason for using `.executesql` when it would be much easier (and safer) to use the DAL's built-in `.update` method?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mistakes in your code. First thing your sql syntax for update query is wrong, you missed quotes around values, your `where` clause is wrong, also string formatting syntax is wrong. You mixed DAL query syntax with sql syntax.

You can easily achieve this using DAL query like this:

```
update_po = db(db.pull_out.sr_id == sr_id).update(po_det=getvars)
```

If you want to do using `executesql`:

```
update_query = "UPDATE pull_out SET po_det='%s' WHERE sr_id='%s';"
update_po = db.executesql(update_query, placeholders=(getvars, sr_id))
```

Comment: Using `executesql` that way makes sql-injection possible. It should be `db.executesql(update_query, placeholders=(getvars, sr_id))`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329598/440323), though there are still two security problems.

First, your server-side code does not do any authentication nor validate the `sr_id` or the value of `request.vars.a`. That means *anyone* can make an HTTP request to this endpoint and update *any* record in `db.pull_out` with *any* value.

Second, if you use the proposed `.executesql` method, you will be open to a SQL injection attack, as it simply inserts the value sent from the (possibly malicious) client directly into the SQL statement. You should instead use the `placeholders` argument:

```
update_query = "UPDATE pull_out SET po_det='%s' WHERE sr_id='%s';" 
update_po = db.executesql(update_query, placeholders=(getvars, sr_id))
```

However, as long as you have already defined the `db.pull_out` table, you might as well use the DAL API to do the update.

Finally, be careful about returning `locals()`, as you might end up leaking non-public data. Better to return a dictionary with just the data needed by your view.

Comment: as always, answer is comprehensive and helpful. Thanks!